# How do I search the contents of registers?

Tags: search, register

I have a bad habit of deleting some text `a`, heading off to another section of the document to paste it, and finding something else along the way that I need to delete.  When I get to my final destination, where I want to paste the originally deleted text `a`, it's no longer in the default register.

I know that this is easy to fix by thinking ahead and deleting the text into a named, rather than the default, register.  However, in the absence of that foresight, what I do instead is hope I haven't deleted too much text in the meantime, and look through the numbered registers until I find `a`.

The problem is that `a` is usually not just a single character, but rather a large block of text, and I might only remember a passage from the middle of that block when I am searching the registers.  Since `:reg` only shows a one-line preview of each register, I can't necessarily find `a` by visual inspection.

Is there a command that I can issue to match a given regex against, not a *specific* register, but *all* registers, and that will tell me, say, "your regex matches in `"3` and `"7`"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a script you can put in `~/.vim/plugin/registers.vim` for a command `:Registers` that does `:registers` on all registers matching the commands argument (pattern).

```
if exists('g:registers')
  finish
endif
let g:registers = 1

const s:registers = [
      \ '"',
      \ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
      \ '_',
      \ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
      \ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
      \ ':', '.', '%',
      \ '#',
      \ '=',
      \ '*', '+', '~',
      \ '/',
      \ ]

function FindMatchingRegister(text) abort
  return s:registers->copy()->filter({_, v -> getreg(v) =~ a:text })
endfunction

command -nargs=1 Registers execute 'registers' FindMatchingRegister(<q-args>)->join()
```

Comment: This is pretty useful; I think I'll stick it in my vimrc! It gives an error if nothing matches though; need a check for that. [This is what I ended up with for now](https://github.com/arp242/dotfiles/blob/ad1c698901186b0a57e4040d55ce1ada3893cd4b/vim/vimrc#L734), but it's Vim9Script. I also changed `nargs` to `*` so `:Registers` will work as `:registers`.

Comment: Also wonder if there isn't a better way to list all register names, but can't find any 

Comment: why listing the '_' register ?

Comment: perhaps use : '"0123456789_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:.%#=*+~/'->split('\zs')->filter()` ?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Hm I think I meant to omit it, but no harm done... I do prefer the explicit list for now though

Comment: @MartinTournoij what error? Normally even `:execute 'registers' ''` or `:execute 'registers' ([]->join())` works just fine.

Comment: I get `E1207: Expression without an effect: registers`

Comment: @MartinTournoij I can't repro that with `8.2.5062` compiled at the beginning of the week, at least not with the commands in my last comment. That would seem like a bug, anyway? `:registers` is definitely a command (not an expression) and it has an effect…

Comment: Looks like it's because I have `vim9script` in my vimrc; the command seems to behave different in that context. It works if I save it to `a.vim` and then `:source a.vim`.

Comment: Can you help me understand how to use this?  I sourced it and then ran `:Registers /abc/`, but it just shows all my registers, none of which contains that string.

Comment: @LSpice with the current code, if there is no match (_i.e._, the result of `FindMatchingRegisters` is empty), then the command does the equivalent of `:registers`. One way to fix this might be to use `command -nargs=1 Registers execute 'registers' (FindMatchingRegister(<q-args>) ?? ['_'])->join()` but it's a bit hacky (`:registers _` is basically always blank).

Comment: [Thanks](https://vi.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/68653)!  I'm sorry for my ignorance, but I do not at all know my way around vimscript.  I tried it again with a regex that I know matches some, but not all, registers—comically, it was `:Registers /def/`—but once again all registers displayed.  Is that not the right way to invoke it, or did I somehow do something else wrong?

Comment: @LSpice woops! I didn't think about your `/`s. They aren't needed, actually: anything after `:Registers` will be used as a single argument to the function, which is then used in the pattern spot. In commands `:substitute` or `:global`, the pattern is the bit _between_ the delimiters (the delimiters themselves are not considered part of the pattern). So simply `:Registers def` should do it. (If you're used to, say, JS or Perl, where `//` look like they create a regexp… they stole the idea from ed/ex/vi/vim. But they got it kinda wrong :P )

Comment: [Thanks](https://vi.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/68655)!  Then this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

"Unnamed" register is not a real one. It's just a pointer. When you delete the text that has more than one line it goes into register 1. The previous text of the register 1 goes into the register 2, and so on upto 9.

Hence your text must be in one of registers 1-9. You can start trying by pasting from the register 1 with <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>. If no luck then press <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to undo and to paste from the register 2, and so on.

Every time you press "dot" the register number will increase by one. This is a special feature documented at `:h redo-register`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>; I didn't know that!  But I did understand about the auto-promotion of numbered registers, and was hoping for something that would save me doing this potentially many times by simply telling me automatically which numbered registers had the desired content.  @ChristianBrabandt's [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37652) is almost exactly what I was looking for, except that it only peers into the first line of each register.

Comment: @LSpice You can implement something like that with a bit of scripting. Or find some plugin that allows to browse through registers content before pasting(smth. about "peek register" in title).

Comment: I believe this is the best suggestion and this tip is very convenient.

Answer (score 5):

In general, I would just use the [:reg](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Aregisters) command to check what is in the various registers.This usually helps already.

But using the [:filter](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Afilter)  command, you can also apply a regex to search inside the register content and only show those registers that match your regex:

```
:filter /regex/ reg
```

So this will filter the output of the `:register` command and only show those, that match the given regular expression `regex`.

Note, that it will only try to match on the first line in the register. This matters, because register can contain many lines.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I want, except the "only … the first line in the register" part.  I guess there's no way to force it to search the full contents of each register?  (This is the same reason that I don't just use `:reg`—I'm looking for content that may be buried many lines deep in the register.)

Comment: nope, no way to make it search everything I believe

Comment: [Thanks](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/37650/how-do-i-search-the-contents-of-registers/37652#comment68601_37652)!  I'll wait a bit in case someone else knows some secret arcana to force it to do so; but, if not, then this is as close as possible to what I want, so I will accept it.

Comment: Thank you very much again for this answer.  It is extremely close to what I want, and built in, which is a plus; but @D.BenKnoble's [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37654) does exactly what I want with some scripting, so I wound up accepting it.  We all know the dilemma—if I could have accepted two, I would have accepted this one too!